# How to decode DynamicKeys & CodingKeys in the same container?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

**Consider the following JSON:** I'm trying to decode the "teams" object.

```
let jsonString = """

{
   "Superheroes":{
   "Marvel":"107",
   "DC":"106"
},
"teams":{
  "106":{
     "name":"Marvel",
     "Superheroes":{
        "890":{
           "name":"Batman"
        }
     }
  },
  "107":{
     "name":"DC",
     "Superheroes":{
        "891":{
           "name":"Wonder Woman"
        }
     }
   }
  }
}

"""
```

I have tried something like this:

```
struct SuperheroResponse: Decodable {

    let teams: [Team]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case teams = "teams"
    }

    private struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let teamContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: CodingKeys.teams)
        print(teamContainer.allKeys.count)
    
        let tempArray: [Team] = []

        for key in teamContainer.allKeys {

            let decodedObject = try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            tempArray.append(decodedObject)
        }

        teams = tempArray
   }
}

struct Team: Decodable {

    let name: String
}
```

I thought that first I would get the teams container, map over the keys and go on from there. Problem is teamContainer.allKeys.count is always zero.

Also the following line, results in following error: Cannot convert value of type 'SuperheroResponse.DynamicCodingKeys' to expected argument type 'SuperheroResponse.CodingKeys'

```
let decodedObject = try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
```

Finally I decode it as follows:

```
let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let decodedResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(SuperheroResponse.self, from: jsonData)

dump(decodedResult)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Ideally I would like something like SuperheroResponse -> [Team],
Team -> name, [Superhero], Superhero -> name

Comment: I would declare the teams property as `let teams: [String: Team]` and then use the values of the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a couple of minor mistakes. You're almost there.

The team container is keyed by DynamicCodingKeys:

```
let teamContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self,  // <=
                                                  forKey: .teams)
```

And the Teams can be decoded as using the key you're given:

```
let decodedObject = try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: key)
```

Also, `tempArray` needs to be var:

```
var tempArray: [Team] = []
```

Or replace that loop with a `map`:

```
    teams = try teamContainer.allKeys.map {
        try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: $0)
    }
```

All together:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let teamContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self, forKey: .teams)
    teams = try teamContainer.allKeys.map {
        try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: $0)
    }
}
```